# Remove method in a Binary Search Tree for Java

Tags: java, search, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

So my interface says that the following qualifications must be cared for:

```
/**
 * Remove the data element from the tree.
 * 
 * In the case that a node you want to remove has two children
 * replace it with the successor. If the data is null throw 
 * IllegalArgumentException.
 * 
 * @param data The data you want to remove.
 *            
 * @return The data that was removed from the tree. Return null if
 *         the data doesn't exist.
 */
public T remove(T data);
```

This is what I have so far with a few additional debugging done:

```
public T remove(T data) {
    if (data == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return removeHelper(data, root);
}

    public T removeHelper(T data, Node<T> node) {
    System.out.println("DATA: " + data);
    System.out.println("NODE: " + node);
    System.out.println(); 

    if (node == null) {
        System.out.println("I should be here last: " + data);
        return data;
    } else if (data.compareTo(node.getData()) < 0) {
        System.out.println("im here");
        removeHelper(data, node.getLeft());
    } else if (data.compareTo(node.getData()) > 0) {
        removeHelper(data, node.getRight());
    } else {
        System.out.println("im here again");
        if (node.getLeft() != null && node.getRight() != null) {
            node.setData(minFromRight(node.getRight()).getData());
            removeHelper(minFromRight(node.getRight()).getData(), node.getRight());
        } else if (node.getLeft() != null) {
            node = node.getLeft();
        } else if (node.getRight() != null) {
            node = node.getRight();
        } else {
            node = null;
            removeHelper(data, node);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private Node<T> minFromRight(Node<T> toTraverse) {
    if (toTraverse.getLeft() == null) {
        return toTraverse;
    } else if (toTraverse.getLeft() != null) {
        minFromRight(toTraverse.getLeft());
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have started to test for leaf node cases and they don't work. Am I doing something wrong? all my other functions of the BST work properly and have been tested thoroughly. I just need to get this darn remove().

Comment: Here is an optional remove method that I found:
[remove method from Habr](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35090424/5857867)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem comes from the fact that you're trying to manipulate the local node variable thinking that it will affect the tree. For example take a look at this part of the code:

```
} else {
     node = null;
     removeHelper(data, node);
}
```

When you say `node = null` you have to take into account that `node` does not represent the real node but instead is a copy of the reference that you passed when you called the function. So if you set `node = null` you are only saying that the local `node` variable does not point to the node in the tree anymore but to null instead.

If you want to delete the node from the tree you will have to reference the parent first and then set the child to null using the parent's reference.