# Deleting Value in Binary Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have a slightly working binary search tree delete value function.  The only time that it does not work is if you are trying to delete a root that has two children.

```
public boolean delete(BinaryTreeNode node, int i){
    if (node == null){
    return false;
    } else {
        if (node.getKey() == i){
            BinaryTreeNode parent = new BinaryTreeNode(0, null, null);
            parent.setLeftChild(root);
            boolean result = deleteHelper(i, node, parent);
            root = parent.getLeftChild();
            return result;
        } else {
            return deleteHelper(i, node, null);
        }
    }
}

public boolean deleteHelper(int value, BinaryTreeNode curr, BinaryTreeNode parent){
    if (value < curr.getKey()){
        if (curr.getLeftChild() != null){
            return deleteHelper(value, curr.getLeftChild(), curr);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (value > curr.getKey()){
        if (curr.getRightChild() != null){
            return deleteHelper(value, curr.getRightChild(), curr);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        if (curr.getRightChild() != null && curr.getLeftChild() != null){
            curr.setKey(findMin(curr.getRightChild()).getKey());
            deleteHelper(curr.getKey(), curr.getRightChild(), curr);
        } else if (parent.getLeftChild() == curr){
            parent.setLeftChild((curr.getLeftChild() != null)?curr.getLeftChild():curr.getRightChild());
        } else if (parent.getRightChild() == curr){
            parent.setRightChild((curr.getLeftChild() != null)?curr.getLeftChild():curr.getRightChild());
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikipedia

Deleting a node with two children: Call the node to be deleted N. Do not delete N. Instead, choose either its in-order successor node or its in-order predecessor node, R. Copy the value of R to N, then recursively call delete on R until reaching one of the first two cases.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion

You can try by successor node as follows:

1. get successor of node to delete (current)
2. connect parent of current to successor
3. connect successor to the left child for current

For more details check out this link

[Java, Binary tree remove method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836212/java-binary-tree-remove-method)